# Discrete Mathematics Wording Difference Between "Show" and "Prove"

Tags: discrete-mathematics, soft-question, terminology

I just took a midterm for a Discrete Mathematics class. On couple of questions, it says "Show why this is true". For example, a sample question might have said "Show that five consecutive numbers is divisible by 120"

My question is, is there a difference between "show" and "proof"?

Comment: If a concrete claim can be simply shown by calculating a concrete example out, the term "show" is usually used. But I read many proofs of general claims where the word "show" was used. Maybe, in such cases, "prove" would be a better choice.

Comment: Often "show" will be used when you need to produce a counter-example to a false-claim (i.e. An example that proves a conjecture is false).

Comment: In general, assume they're synonyms.

Answer (score 1):

Stylistically there may be reasons to use one or the other, but in general I'd say that "show" and "prove" are synonyms.